# Rails set filter by the current user - joins association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a filter I'm using for a form that I'd like to only show those that have an email that matches the current user.

Attributes involved: Users' email, Career's recipient, Region name

Careers belongs_to :region and I'm currently displaying Region with the following in my view:

```
-@careers.each do |career|
 th =career.region&.name
```

So the logic would be to compare current_user.email against all Careers.recipienct and if present then display only those Regions that are represented.

Example would be:

```
Region            | Career       | Recipients
Pacific Northwest | Data Analyst | john@doe.com, jill@excite.com
```

So I know it needs to hit my region select which looks like:

```
= select_tag :region_id,
  options_from_collection_for_select(sort_region, :id, :name, params[:region_id]),
  include_blank: 'All Regions'
```

sort_region currently has:

```
def sort_region
 Region.where.not(name: ['HQ', 'Canada'].sort_by(&:position)
end
```

So my thought was to tackle the comparison in something similar with:

```
def user_region
 if current_user.super_admin?
  return sort_region
 else 
  arr = []
  Career.all.each do |emails|
   arr << emails.recipient
  end
  if arr.include?(current_user.email)
   return BLANK
  end
 end
end
```

The blank is where I'm stuck. I only want to show those Regions where there is a match of the Career.recipient with the current_user.email.

I wrote the following for the return that basically I hate

```
return Region.joins(:career).where("region.name = career.region&.name")
```

This actually returns

> Can't join 'Region' to association named 'career'

Same issue when I try

```
return Region.joins(:career).where("careers.region_id = region.id")
```

Is there a correct joins association I should be using here?

EDIT:
I think I could address the return if I could figure out how to push to the array a second value with the email.

So something like:

```
  arr = []
  Career.all.each do |emails|
    arr << emails.recipient
    arr << emails.region_id
  end
  if arr.include?(current_user.email)
    return region_id
  end
```

So this doesn't create a pair like I'd hope/want of [["john@doe.com", 2], ["jane@excite.com", 3]] but instead ["john@doe.com", 2, "jane@excite.com", 3]. Also I'm not able to do a return on region_id. So I'd need to access the integers only.

Maybe I should be creating a hash of all the items and then pull from there?

Another EDIT:

Tried putting the conditional within the iteration.

```
arr = []
Career.all.each do |emails|
 if emails.recipient == current_user.email
  arr << emails.region_id
 end
end
```

This however shows the arr containing [1] which is not the associated region_id.

Third EDIT:

My latest attempt has been to see about doing a join where I simply pull out those Regions where Career Recipient equals the current_user.email.

```
Region.find(:all, joins: ' JOIN regions ON careers.region_id', conditions: "#{current_user.email} = careers.recipient")
```

This results in The Region you were looking for could not be found.

Comment: This Error `Can't join 'Region' to association named 'career'` can be corrected by `Region.joins(:careers)` as I assume based on the rest of your code, that a `Region` has many `Careers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arel_table for the win

```
Region.joins(:careers).where(Career.arel_table[:recipient].matches("%#{current_user.email}%"))
```